# Why JSON return value has changed when migrating from .net core 3.1 to .net 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-5

I have an ASP.NET Web API that I have migrated from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 5, it seems that the return values in my JSON have changed as a result of this. I've looked around but can't find anything as to why this might be happening, I have included both JSON return values below.

I only discovered this was an issue because when I upgraded to .NET 5 my Blazor API call was throwing a JSON exception saying that it could not map to the model which makes sense now that I have pulled the JSON back from each version in Postman.

Any help or information would be really appreciated.

C# Code

```
    // GET: api/a/get-all
    [HttpGet("get-all")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
    {
        var as = await _context.A.Include(p => p.PT)
                                          .Include(bt => bt.BT)
                                          .Include(bf => bf.BF)
                                          .Include(e => e.E)
                                          .Include(b => b.B)
                                          .Include(ar => ar.Ar)
                                          .Include(a => a.A)
                                          .Include(o => o.O)
                                          .Include(c => c.C)
                                          .Include(b => b.B)
                                          .ToListAsync();

        if (as == null)
            return NotFound(new { errorMessage = "It seems there are no A's in the database, please enter at least one." });

        return Ok(as);
    }
```

.Net Core 3.1

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "propertyOne": "valueOne",
        "propertyTwo": "valueTwo"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "propertyOne": "valueOne",
        "propertyTwo": "valueTwo"
    }
]
```

.Net 5

```
{
"$id": "1",
"$values": [
    {
        "$id": "2",
        "id": 1,
        "propertyOne": "valueOne",
        "propertyTwo": "valueTwo"
    },
    {
        "$id": "4",
        "id": 4,
        "propertyOne": "valueOne",
        "propertyTwo": "valueTwo"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: How is the Json produced? What is your code?

Comment: I've updated to include the C# code, I have renamed the tables to just single letters.

Comment: You seem to have zero separation between your database models and your web transfer models. Don't do that. Create seperate entities for your web models, map your database models to them and then return your web model classes. I'm not sure what your *current* problem is, but you will continue to have theses problems if you just pump out your raw database models over the API.

Comment: Yeah, not really concerned with DTO's at the moment, I have secured the API (it won't be exposed publicly anyway).

Comment: Well, what I'm telling you is that you are not in control of the objects you pass, so you are not in control of the JSON you produce. As that seems to be your problem... one possible solution would be to have a proper layer of DTOs.

Comment: That could be the solution to my problem but just wondering why this has happened in the first place, is it some fundamental change with how the JSON is generated and sent, I will implement a DTO for this model and see if that helps.

Comment: You said you migrated. Maybe the database classes look different internally now. Maybe it's something with the json serializer picking up fields they should not. Both things that can happen again with any nuget package update of the serializer or your database packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Blazor project was having trouble mapping to the model because the deserializer was not expecting the metadata in the JSON. In my JsonSerializerOptions, I added the ReferenceHandler ReferenceHandler.Preserve option and this fixed the issue for me.

```
JsonSerializerOptions options = new()
    {
        ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve
    };
```